# Time complexity of computing general imminant

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, matrices

Consider the immanent of $n \times n$ complex matrices

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Imm}_f(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} f_n(\sigma) A_{1 \sigma(1)} \cdots A_{n \sigma(n)}.
\end{equation}
Here $f_n:\pi \to \mathbb{C}.$ I want to investigate the computational complexity of such function by given family of $f_n$.

**Special cases 1:** when $f_n=\chi$ is the character of an irreducible representation of $S_n$.

When $\chi$ is trivial, we get permanent which is # $P$ complete by Valiant's theorem. On the other hand, if $\chi(\pi)=sgn(\pi),$ we get the determinant which can be computed in $O(n^3)$.
[See discussion here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/130947/time-complexity-of-the-immanant?newreg=3b47e98817254b58b6630465304f6fcd)

For the general character $\chi$, there are extensive results,
[The Complexity of the Fermionant and
Immanants of Constant Width](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v009a006/v009a006.pdf) and  [A full complexity dichotomy for immanant families](https://A%20full%20complexity%20dichotomy%20for%20immanant%20families), basically one can count the certain shape of the box in the young tableaux of the representation.

**Special cases 2:**
when $f$ is not a character but the **class function**, we know that character is complete, so we can compute *the inner product between $f$ and all the character*. I believe one can show complexity via this way. If overlap of f with simple character is large enough, the result will in $P$. Otherwise will # $P$.

**my question**
But how about the computation complexity for general $f_n$? Now I have a function family and I can prove that $\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi \in S_n} f_n(\pi) \to 0, $ as $n \to \infty,$ this shows that $f_n$ is orthogonal to the trivial character as $n$ large enough. Is it at least give the hint that $Imm_{f}(A)$ may be easy to compute? I know I need to compute all the inner products with other characters but whether this idea works for general $f$.

Or how should I deal with general $f_n$ if $f_n$ is not a class function? I have not yet seen any paper discussing such results.

Any idea or comment are welcome

Comment: Characters other than the trivial character are also orthogonal to the trivial character, but the corresponding immanants are mostly hard to compute.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I know this, but how should one generally attack this problem, for general f?

Comment: It should be hard for most $f$.

Comment: Thanks professor, so you mean is that most f will make it hard to compute or attack(Proof) general f is hard?

Comment: Both, probably.